# How to Break Lines in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable called *hidden* as follows in my JS file:

```
var hidden=$('#hidden').val();
```

When i alert variable *hidden*, Output is

```
Need for voice connection\n\ with text messaging pack\n\  and 3G data
```

But i need Output as

```
Need for voice connection
with text messaging pack
and 3G data
```

How to achieve it? In Javascript

Comment: is your `#hidden` a text area?

Comment: Seems like the value *literally* contains the character sequence `\n`. Why and why doesn't it contain real line breaks?

Comment: @FelixKling — It's an HTML attribute value.

Comment: @reddy - Yes. its a textarea

Comment: @Quentin: Apparently it's the value of a textarea, which has no problem containing line breaks: https://jsfiddle.net/35nqLm3x/ . Just trying to get the whole context here and finding out whether using actual line breaks from the beginning is possible :)

Answer (score 2):

So you have a string containing `\n\` to represent new lines?

Replace those characters with actual new lines.

```js
var data = "Need for voice connection\\n\\ with text messaging pack\\n\\  and 3G data";
alert("Original: " + data);
data = data.replace(/\\n\\ /g, "\n");
alert("Replaced: " + data);
```

Comment: @Quentin- Perfect. Its Working. What is the workaround for same in JAVA?

Comment: I've managed to avoid writing any Java since about 2003. The work around will be the same though (probably, depending on what *exactly* you are doing with the strings), just with different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`alert('test\\n\\test2\\n\\test3\\n\\test4'.replace(new RegExp(/\\n\\/g), '\n');`

I'm replacing all excaped `\n` elements with non-escaped character.

Comment: That only replaces the **first** `\n`, and the sequence to replace is `\n\ ` anyway. You should probably test it using the string the OP has instead of one which doesn't have the `\n\ ` sequences in it at all

Comment: After your edit, it replaces exactly 2 instances of it (and leaves a ``\`` behind). Why not write something generic?

Comment: `new RegExp(/\\n\\/g)` is the same as `/\\n\\/g`. Only use `RegExp` if you want to use the value of a *string* as a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with having text area and you type in some sentences with line breaks, it must output as expected. Here is a demo ..

```js
$('#viewValue').on('click', function() {
  var hidden = $('#hidden').val();
  alert(hidden);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="hidden">Need for voice connection
with text messaging pack
and 3G data</textarea>

<button id="viewValue">view</button>
```

---

If at all you are literally typing the characters `\n` and expecting the line breaks then you must put in some extra efforts to get your desired output.

Replace `\n` with a new line character using regex. Demo as below

```js
$('#viewValue').on('click', function() {
  var hidden = $('#hidden').val().replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
  debugger;
  alert(hidden);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="hidden">Need for voice connection \n with text messaging pack \n and 3G data</textarea>

<button id="viewValue">view</button>
```